# Import xlsx file from folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have script that perfectly work on google sheet and import files from folder  to one file.
But when i want import files xlsx-format from folder to one file it gives: "Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 1mvo7w1k320cqYqf5sK2YQrDqCRIt59iM"

What the problem whith script

```
function Import_Kredo() {
  var arr = [];
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("13kymSiqX0-L6a9ev4It1_BEjH-xM8rnc").getFiles();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Table 1")
  copySheet.getRange('A2:G').clear();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();

    var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId())
    var sheets = ss1.getSheetByName("Table 1")
    var sheetsRange = sheets.getDataRange()
    var sheetsValues = sheetsRange.getValues().filter(r => r[1]).filter(e => e)
    arr = arr.concat(sheetsValues.slice(1))
  }

copySheet.getRange(5, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr)
}
```

I tried to inport files from folder to one file, but in geves mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, in the current stage, the values cannot be directly retrieved from the XLSX data using the Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp). In order to retrieve the values from XLSX data using Google Apps Script, in this answer, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. When the file is XLSX data, convert XLSX data to Google Spreadsheet. When the file is Spreadsheet, your script is used.
2. Retrieve the values from converted Spreadsheet.
3. Put the values to the sheet you expect.
4. Remove the converted Spreadsheet.

When this flow is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function Import_Kredo() {
  var arr = [];
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("13kymSiqX0-L6a9ev4It1_BEjH-xM8rnc").getFiles();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Table 1");
  copySheet.getRange('A2:G').clear();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var mimeType = file.getMimeType();
    var ss1 = null, id = null;
    if (mimeType == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL) {
      id = Drive.Files.copy({ mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS }, file.getId()).id;
      ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    } else if (mimeType == MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS) {
      ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
    }
    if (!ss1) continue;
    var sheet = ss1.getSheetByName("Table 1");
    if (!sheet) continue;
    var sheetsRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var sheetsValues = sheetsRange.getValues().filter(r => r[1]).filter(e => e);
    var v = sheetsValues.slice(1);
    console.log([file.getName(), v])
    arr = arr.concat([[file.getName(), ...Array(v[0].length - 1).fill(null)], ...v]);
    if (id) DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true); // or Drive.Files.remove(id);
  }
  copySheet.getRange(5, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
}
```

- When this script is run, when the file is XLSX data, it is converted to Google Spreadsheet. And, when the file is Google Spreadsheet, your script is used.

#### Reference:

- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy)

Comment: It is works, thank you. Maybe you know how to add the names of files in first column, because it will be 28 files for import

Comment: @Елена Желевская Thank you for replying. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: it add name of file onli in 1-st cell and then import 1-st column of file and i need that 1 -st column will be name of file that dublicate to all cell till import

Comment: @Елена Желевская Thank you for replying. About your new question of `it add name of file onli in 1-st cell and then import 1-st column of file and i need that 1 -st column will be name of file that dublicate to all cell till import `, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do about your new question. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your new question?

Comment: @Елена Желевская I could understand your 1st question and resolve it. But, I cannot understand your 2nd question. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. But, I would like to support you. So, I would like to try to understand your new question. When I could correctly understand your new question, I would like to think of a solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot understand your various questions soon. I think that I have to study English more.

Comment: i am bad in english too, sorry. I need first column - name of file, that we import from the folder, and other from file

Comment: @Елена Желевская Thank you for replying. About `first column - name of file, that we import from the folder`, from your additional request of `Maybe you know how to add the names of files in first column, because it will be 28 files for import` in your reply, I added it in my answer. How about it?

Comment: it will be great